# Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = timeout expired while starting chaincode fabcar

Tags: docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric

I'm following the tutorial as-is given here - http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html

I'm working on Mac OS : High Sierra.

I'm getting error as below:

> Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc =
>   timeout expired while starting chaincode
>   fabcar:1.0(networkid:dev,peerid:peer0.org1.example.com,tx:c51ca82792bd8823a60edf9c31a550836fc8932a90a2a4cec8b9c37ba24c46ea)

Thanks for the help.

command: `./startFabric.sh node`

complete logs:

```
# don't rewrite paths for Windows Git Bash users
   export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1

   docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml down
   Stopping peer0.org1.example.com ... done
   Stopping orderer.example.com    ... done
   Stopping ca.example.com         ... done
   Stopping couchdb                ... done
   Removing peer0.org1.example.com ... done
   Removing orderer.example.com    ... done
   Removing ca.example.com         ... done
   Removing couchdb                ... done
   Removing network net_basic

   docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d ca.example.com orderer.example.com 
   peer0.org1.example.com couchdb
   Creating network "net_basic" with the default driver
   Creating orderer.example.com ... done
   Creating ca.example.com      ... done
   Creating couchdb             ... done
   Creating peer0.org1.example.com ... done

   # wait for Hyperledger Fabric to start
   # incase of errors when running later commands, issue export 
   FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT=<larger number>
   export FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT=10
   #echo ${FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT}
   sleep ${FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT}

   # Create the channel
   docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e 
   "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" 
   peer0.org1.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c 
   mychannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/channel.tx
   2018-05-03 17:56:04.275 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser 
   and orderer connections initialized
   2018-05-03 17:56:04.392 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 002 Endorser 
   and orderer connections initialized
   2018-05-03 17:56:04.621 UTC [main] main -> INFO 003 Exiting.....
   # Join peer0.org1.example.com to the channel.
   docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e 
   "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" 
   peer0.org1.example.com peer channel join -b mychannel.block
   2018-05-03 17:56:04.861 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser 
   and orderer connections initialized
   2018-05-03 17:56:05.018 UTC [channelCmd] executeJoin -> INFO 002 Successfully 
   submitted proposal to join channel
   2018-05-03 17:56:05.018 UTC [main] main -> INFO 003 Exiting.....
   Creating cli ... done
   2018-05-03 17:56:06.745 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing 
   local MSP
   2018-05-03 17:56:06.745 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 
   Obtaining default signing identity
   2018-05-03 17:56:06.746 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 003 
   Using default escc
   2018-05-03 17:56:06.746 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 004 
   Using default vscc
   2018-05-03 17:56:06.746 UTC [chaincodeCmd] getChaincodeSpec -> DEBU 005 java 
   chaincode disabled
   2018-05-03 17:56:06.749 UTC [node-platform] GetDeploymentPayload -> DEBU 006 
   Packaging node.js project from path /opt/gopath/src/github.com/fabcar/node
   2018-05-03 17:56:06.749 UTC [container] WriteFolderToTarPackage -> INFO 007 
   rootDirectory = /opt/gopath/src/github.com/fabcar/node
   2018-05-03 17:56:06.752 UTC [container] WriteFileToPackage -> DEBU 008 Writing 
   file to tarball: src/fabcar.js
   2018-05-03 17:56:06.762 UTC [container] WriteFileToPackage -> DEBU 009 Writing 
   file to tarball: src/package.json
   2018-05-03 17:56:06.765 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 00a Sign: plaintext: 
   0A9C070A5C08031A0C08B69AADD70510...C1F84F000000FFFF22CB6E3A001E0000 
   2018-05-03 17:56:06.765 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 00b Sign: digest: 
   CAD5821E4354EA410ED3567BE82D12813B469783B96FB8EEE2A1B4416A323B76 
   2018-05-03 17:56:06.816 UTC [chaincodeCmd] install -> DEBU 00c Installed 
   remotely response:<status:200 payload:"OK" > 
   2018-05-03 17:56:06.816 UTC [main] main -> INFO 00d Exiting.....
   2018-05-03 17:56:07.116 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing 
   local MSP
   2018-05-03 17:56:07.116 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 
   Obtaining default signing identity
   2018-05-03 17:56:07.121 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 003 
   Using default escc
   2018-05-03 17:56:07.121 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 004 
   Using default vscc
   2018-05-03 17:56:07.123 UTC [chaincodeCmd] getChaincodeSpec -> DEBU 005 java 
   chaincode disabled
   2018-05-03 17:56:07.125 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 006 Sign: plaintext: 
   0AA6070A6608031A0B08B79AADD70510...324D53500A04657363630A0476736363 
   2018-05-03 17:56:07.126 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 007 Sign: digest: 
   7574A79A053907A7CD90E656B612CE20AA80E95067403F097B3F6185EC25D329 
   Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = timeout 
   expired while starting chaincode fabcar:1.0(networkid:dev,peerid:peer0.org1.example.com,tx:c51ca82792bd8823a60edf9c31a550836fc8932a90a2a4cec8b9c37ba24c46ea)
   Usage:
     peer chaincode instantiate [flags]

     Flags:
      -C, --channelID string            The channel on which this command should be executed
      --collections-config string   The file containing the configuration for the chaincode's collection
      -c, --ctor string                 Constructor message for the chaincode in JSON format (default "{}")
      -E, --escc string                 The name of the endorsement system chaincode to be used for this chaincode
      -l, --lang string                 Language the chaincode is written in (default "golang")
      -n, --name string                 Name of the chaincode
      -P, --policy string               The endorsement policy associated to this chaincode
      -v, --version string              Version of the chaincode specified in install/instantiate/upgrade commands
      -V, --vscc string                 The name of the verification system chaincode to be used for this chaincode

   Global Flags:
      --cafile string                       Path to file containing PEM-encoded 
   trusted certificate(s) for the ordering endpoint
      --certfile string                     Path to file containing PEM-encoded 
   X509 public key to use for mutual TLS communication with the orderer endpoint
      --clientauth                          Use mutual TLS when communicating with 
   the orderer endpoint
      --keyfile string                      Path to file containing PEM-encoded 
   private key to use for mutual TLS communication with the orderer endpoint
      --logging-level string                Default logging level and overrides, 
   see core.yaml for full syntax
      -o, --orderer string                      Ordering service endpoint
          --ordererTLSHostnameOverride string   The hostname override to use when 
   validating the TLS connection to the orderer.
      --tls                                 Use TLS when communicating with the 
   orderer endpoint
      --transient string                    Transient map of arguments in JSON 
   encoding
```

Answer (score 0):

Timeout issue is a common issue that occurs during instantiation of a chaincode. What can help you is that after issuing the

```
peer chaincode instantiate
```

command or when the logs reach to this state

```
[chaincodeCmd] install -> DEBU 00c Installed remotely response:<status:200 payload:"OK" >
```

, in a separate terminal, list the docker containers using

```
docker ps
```

You'll notice a container with a random name that you've never heard before and its image (fabric-ccenv) shows that its a secure docker container that is started for establishing chaincode environment. Note the name of the container and tail its logs using

```
docker logs -f <container-name-here>
```

now you'll see in the logs that its actually resolving the npm dependencies listed in the chaincode's package.json. The dependency resolution sometimes takes a bit larger than the expected time and hence the fabric runtime exits with the timeout issue. If the fabric script exits with the timeout issue, then you have to exec into the peer docker container and execute the

```
peer chaincode instantiate [flags]
```

command manually providing necessary flags and params. In case the dependencies are perfectly resolved, the chaincode will start within seconds this time.

Comment: Thank you for responding. 
I see bunch of errors in the docker logs complaining '... could not connect to any of the endpoints : [orderer.example.com:7050]

Comment: 018-05-03 23:07:29.927 UTC [kvledger] CommitWithPvtData -> INFO 03d Channel [mychannel]: Committed block [4] with 1 transaction(s)
... [deliveryClient] try -> WARN 03e Got error: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing , at 1 attempt. Retrying in 1s
... [ConnProducer] NewConnection -> ERRO 03f Failed connecting to orderer.example.com:7050 , error: context deadline exceeded
... UTC [deliveryClient] connect -> ERRO 040 Failed obtaining connection: Could not connect to any of the endpoints: [orderer.example.com:7050]

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem. I resolved it by ensuring that docker containers start in the correct order. For example, the orderer container should start before the peers start. If the containers don't start in the right order, I faced problems while creating the channel (SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE) or while instantiating the chaincode(time out error).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error. In my case the problem was that the name of project folder was not the same as the network name, these names are somehow related and must be the same. I renamed the folder and the problem was gone.